# Android Kotlin Recycle View reloadData

Tags: android, kotlin

I have "problem" with this:

[image],

where P button is Previous, and N as Next, both button call:

```
private fun fetchJson(date: String) {
        val url = "https://xxx/$date.json"
        println("URL: $url")
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val responseData = response.body()?.string()

                runOnUiThread {
                    var rows: List<Product> = emptyList()

                    try {
                        if (response.code() in 200..399) {
                            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                            rows = gson.fromJson(responseData, Array<Product>::class.java).toList()

                            recycleView.adapter = ProductsAdapter(this@DetailsActivity, rows)
                            (recycleView.adapter as ProductsAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()

                        }
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed")
            }
        })
    }
```

and Products Adapter Class

```
class ProductsAdapter(private val context: Context, private val rows: List<Product>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsAdapter.ProductViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.product_item, parent, false)
        return ProductViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return rows.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val row = rows[position]
        holder.setData(row, position)
    }

    inner class ProductViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun setData(row: Product, position: Int) {
            /// set data
        }
    }
}
```

also XML for recycle view is:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#E9DA1616"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vipBtn" />
```

and the main problem is when tap on N or P button, data is there but recyclerView did not reload with new data. Only show product (populate recyclerview) first time.

Where I go wrong? I just start with Android and Kotlin, every tutorial says `notifyDataSetChanged()` this will do the job, but not...

Thanks

Comment: Some debug question. Did you check `date` parameter has different values after each call? Is `recycleView.adapter` reassigning code ever reached?

Comment: Yes, also try this ```val dt = Date()
        val url = "https://example.com/$date.json?dt=${dt.time}"``` just to be sure... but the problem stays

Comment: make sure your aarray and gson is not empty

Comment: Thanks @unzila but yes, I checked this hundred times...still not reload

Comment: @miff you debug it ? its not empty ?

Comment: yes of course, and I get data as should be

Comment: Are you sure the HTTP call is correct? Do you pass the new date each time you click the NEXT/PREVIOUS buttons? Add logs to the line where you get the rows (to check if the rows list is not empty) and create a new adapter.

Comment: @Angelina yes I get the data from server, println(), debug w/ breakpoints... whenever I call fetchJson function I create adapter `recycleView.adapter = ProductsAdapter(this@DetailsActivity, rows)`

Comment: What I mean maybe you get the same data thats why you see the same data :-) You cannot have problem with reloading because each time you receive rows you create a new Adapter. You would need `notifydatasetchanged()` when you take reference of the created adapter, take items list and call clear() and then addAll() on them. Then you would need to notify data set changed.

Comment: Thanks @Angelina, I just post the answer :( needit all day to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try recyclerView.invalidate() after pass new data

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Just wow!

I have some experience in iOS and this is literally my 10th hour of Android development, but this is so strange.

My layout from question is constraint layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".DetailsActivity">
[...]
```

I just change to relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0A7463">
[...]
```

and now it's working! Amazing.

This is strange that layout define behavior of component.

Comment: did you have constraints on the recyclerview in your ConstraintLayout? RL and CL have many differences: RL has match_parent and CL has match constraint ("0dp")

Comment: Yes, all around elements, using Design view

Answer (score 0):

To Reload the data in recyclerview you can use below things.
First, add this method in your adapter class.

```
public fun setData(rowData:List<Product>){
   this.row = rowData
   notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

After that below these lines in

```
private fun fetchJson(date: String) {
    val url = "https://xxx/$date.json"
    println("URL: $url")
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val responseData = response.body()?.string()

            runOnUiThread {
                var rows: List<Product> = emptyList()

                try {
                    if (response.code() in 200..399) {
                        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                        rows = gson.fromJson(responseData,Array<Product>::class.java).toList()

                        recycleView.adapter.setData(rows)


                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("Failed")
        }
    })
}
```